# Parse Json array response in scala\Play

Tags: scala, playframework

There is a web service returning array of something

```
{"apps": [{"name": "one"}, {"name": "two"}]}
```

In my code I want to iterate every name

```
val request = WS.url(s"http://localhost:9000/getData")

val json = request.get.map { response =>
  (response.json \ "apps" \\ "name")
}

json.foreach(println)
```

However all my attempts return single record

```
// Expect
one
two
// Actual
ListBuffer("one", "two")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the neat solution here would be:

```
val request = WS.url(s"http://localhost:9000/getData")

request.get.map { response =>
  val names = (response.json \ "apps" \\ "name")
  names.foreach(println)
}
```

Secondly, if you don't want to get confused about the types, you should change your naming standards. For a `Future` object, you may start with the prefix `future`, for an `Option`, it could start with `maybe`, etc. If you do so, the problem in your example will be more obvious:

```
val request = WS.url(s"http://localhost:9000/getData")

val futureJson = request.get.map { response =>
  (response.json \ "apps" \\ "name")
}

futureJson.foreach(println) // you call foreach for a Future, not for a List
```

Thirdly, why would `Future` trait have a method called `foreach`? I think that's confusing for beginners and even mid-level developers. We know from other languages that, foreach means iterate over a list of objects. In Scala, it is considered part of "Monadic operations" which is still a gray area for me :), but the comment for `Future.foreach` in Scala source is this:

```
  /** Asynchronously processes the value in the future once the value becomes available.
   *
   *  Will not be called if the future fails.
   */
  def foreach[U]
```

Comment: Thanks, for solution, explanation and suggestions. Indeed I'm beginner in scala.

Answer (score 1):

Your value of `json` is actually a `Future[Seq[JsValue]]`, so when you `foreach` over the future you get the entire list back.  You would need an additional `foreach` to iterate over the list of values.